# Set open graph tags for a page requiring login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've built a PHP based site that requires a user to log in to view certain pages. I want my users to be able to share these pages (and their custom open graph tags) on Facebook, however when I added my share button, Facebook could not share the correct open graph tags because the page requires you to be logged in. Does anyone know a way around this other than creating a page with the correct open graph tags that doesn't require a login?

I tested the Facebook sharing debugger and it shows the 'canonical URL' as the page you get re-directed to if you are not logged in.

Comment: You could try adding a query string to your redirect URL that identifies the page the user is attempting to access, then change the OG tags of the login page to be those of the intended page? You might already be doing something to redirect the user to the intended page after login, but using the query string in the URL should (hopefully) stop Facebook from caching the tags from a previous request.

Comment: Only thing you can do, is add an exception to your automatic redirect for the FB scraper (can be recognized by its User-Agent request header, see Social Plugins FAQ), so that it can read the meta data directly from the URL. That of course means, everybody who would fake that same User-Agent, would also get to see that content without being logged in.

Comment: But depending on where you want to share, this might not make the most of sense in the first place. In a private group where all users are members of your site it might make sense - but posting on user/page timelines, where other users that do not have an account on your site get to see it in their newsfeeds, will likely just lead to frustration when those users follow the link from Facebook, expecting to see content, but get a login page thrown in their face instead ...

Comment: Thanks guys. @Gavin - I am doing something similar but Facebook does still cache the tags from the previous page : (

Comment: @CBroe, I think I'll go down the route of creating a non-login page that just has the OG tags I need...& when the user visits that they get redirected to the right page (if logged in). The real life use for this is I've created a sports app that allows users to create a league and add other users. I want the league 'admin' user to be able to invite users to join the league, so the OG tags need to differer for the 'admin' user as opposed to just a standard member of the league